# Eaton AFCI/GFCI breaker is only blinking once when turning it on

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, afci

- Model: [CHFN120A1CS](https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/skuPage.CHFN120A1CS.html)
- Description: Eaton CH arc fault / ground    fault circuit breaker, All-In-One, 20A, 10 kAIC , Single-pole, 120V, pigtail, 3/4" AFCI/GFCI

I bought two of these breakers and they both behave exactly the same. They both seem to work properly. They shut off when I test them via the button on the breaker as well as trigger a ground fault using a testing tool.

The main thing that concerns me is that when I flip the breakers ON, the LED light quickly blinks just once. According to the instructions it seems like it should blink 3 times very quickly (within the first half second), indicating that the circuit board is protecting on 20amps. (1 blink = "Uncommon", 2 blinks = 15a, 3 blinks = 20a).

I can't seem to find the same instructions I have online for some reason.

Is this a problem? Is it protecting as AFCI and GFCI? Am I misunderstanding the instructions?

Here are the paper instructions, since I can't find a link to them online:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a link to the proper instruction leaflet for your breaker? It seems that there have been some P/N changes...

Comment: IL003022EN effective November 2018

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/oAsuQew

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/225445/eaton-chfn120a1cs-breaker-status-led-shows-uncommon-issue-and-stays-lit-all-th This was the best answer I could find.

Answer (score -3):

It is not possible for your eyes to see a light bulb turn on and off 60 times per second. Your brain fills in the dark cycle. 3 times in half a second is improbable for a person to detect. If you could blink your eyes fast enough you might be able to detect it.

Comment: A lightbulb actually  "turns off" 120 times per second (or 100 in the rest of the world.) That's quite different from 6 times per second, which is quite visible. Movie frame rates are generally 4 times that fast.

Comment: But don't take my word for it - download a strobe app on your phone and see for yourself. 6 is easily countable. Without the distraction of watching a movie, 24 is clearly blinking, but too fast to count. Blurring to the point of appearing continuous takes considerably higher rates.